# What is the difference between find . and find . -print

Tags: command-line, find

What is the difference between:

```
find .
```

and

```
find . -print
```

What does `-print` actually do?

```
$ find .
.
./hello.txt
./hello
./hello/txt
./hello/hello2
./hello/hello2/hello3
./hello/hello2/hello3/txt
./hello/hello2/txt
$ find . -print
.
./hello.txt
./hello
./hello/txt
./hello/hello2
./hello/hello2/hello3
./hello/hello2/hello3/txt
./hello/hello2/txt
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

From the `findutils` [`find` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> If no expression is given, the expression **`-print`** is used (but you should probably consider using **`-print0`** instead, anyway).

(`-print` is a [`find` expression](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html#EXPRESSION).)

The [POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) confirms this:

> If no *expression* is present, **-print** shall be used as the expression.

So `find .` is exactly equivalent to `find . -print`; the first has no expression so `-print` is added internally.

The explanation of what `-print` does comes further down in the manpage:

> **`-print`**
>
> True; print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a newline.   If you are piping the output of find into another program and there is the faintest possibility that the files which you are searching for might contain a newline, then you should seriously consider using the **`-print0`** option instead of **`-print`**.  See the UNUSUAL FILENAMES section for information about how unusual characters in filenames are handled.

Answer (score 25):

`-print` is the default *action*. Some `find` predicates are considered as *actions* as opposed to *filters* or *conditions*. For instance, `-type f` is not an action. `-exec` is an action even though it can also be used as a condition.

Actions include `-print`, `-exec` and `-ok`. Some `find` implementations have other non-standard action predicates like the `-print0`, `-printf`, `-execdir`, `-okdir`, `-ls`...

```
find files <some-predicates>
```

Where none of *`<some-predicates>`* contain *actions* is equivalent to:

```
find files \( <some-predicates> \) -print
```

(note the parentheses above which are important if there are some `-o` operators).

When in doubt, best is to use `-print` explicitly (or `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +` (or `-print0` where available) so that output can be post-processed).

The default `-print` action is specified by POSIX. [Some old `find` implementations required an explicit `-print`](http://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/find/#print), but those are usually not found in the wild nowadays.

Also note that some `find` implementations allow omitting the `files`, in which case they default to searching into the current directory. That is, for them,

```
find
find -print
```

is equivalent to

```
find .
find . -print
```

That is however not standard, so is best avoided.

On the more verbose (and useful) end of the spectrum, some `find` implementations also allow passing file paths as argument to a `-f` option as in:

```
find -f "$file1" -f "$file2" -print
```

They are the only `find` implementations that allow passing arbitrary file paths to `find`. Other implementations cannot accept file paths like `!` or `-print`... so `find "$file" -print` (or even `find -- "$file" -print`) assumes `$file` is not the name of a `find` predicate (or option in the first case).

Unfortunately that's not standard nor portable either.

Comment: If it is non-standard and *is best avoided* why name it at all?

Comment: @Isaac, because they can be handy/are possible typos...

Answer (score 9):

They are the same, they both write out the entire directory hierarchy from the current directory.

From [POSIX find documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_17):

> The following commands are equivalent:
>
> find .
>
> find . -print

Answer (score 3):

In Linux there is no difference, but other systems (like AIX for instance) need `-print` if you want the output of the command displayed on your screen.

Comment: That would be very very old versions of AIX then. AIX 4.3 `find` doesn't need it. AIX has been POSIX conformant for decades.

Answer (score 3):

For many years the find command did not have a default action.   A common error was forgetting to add the -print option to your find command.   I still to this day type it out of habit.

But at some point it was added as the default action so now `find .` and `find . -print` are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

It is sometimes useful to use `-print` explicitly when you are performing another action so the filename is displayed as that action is performed.

```
find . -print -delete
```

would be similar to

```
rm -rfv *
```

where `-print` corresponds to `-v`. If you don't include `-print` then the filenames aren't displayed.

In order to make the `rm` command even more similar, by the way, issue this Bash command first

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

which will make the `*` match dot (hidden) files.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The question asks why `find .` and `find . -print` seemingly generates identical output and what the role of `-print` is in that example.  Your answer seems to want to talk about `-print` in general terms, which would have been ok if you _also_ had answered the question.