# A confusion about the parameter "-print" in the command "find"

Tags: find

I am new bee for Linux. I have a question about the command `find`. When I search a file under a directory, I would like to skip a sub-directory named `publish`

```
find ./ -path ./publish -prune -o -iname rdesvc -type f -print
```

It works fine:

```
./release/apps/rdeSvc/server/linux/rdeSvc
```

But, if I remove the parameter `-print`:

```
find ./ -path ./publish -prune -o -iname rdesvc -type f
```

It will output the sub-directory name with the search result:

```
./publish
./release/apps/rdeSvc/server/linux/rdeSvc
```

I feel confusion. Why the sub-directory name `publish` is outputted if I removed the parameter `-print`?

My distribution is CentOS 6.6 64 bit.

Comment: See [find: prune does not ignore specified path](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109900/find-prune-does-not-ignore-specified-path)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a combination of [`find`'s default action being `-print`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197827/86440) and [`find`'s operator precedence](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276575/86440).

```
find ./ -path ./publish -prune -o -iname rdesvc -type f -print
```

is interpreted as

```
find ./ \( -path ./publish -prune \) -o \( -iname rdesvc -type f -print \)
```

so `./publish` is pruned, and anything matching `rdesvc` is printed.

But

```
find ./ -path ./publish -prune -o -iname rdesvc -type f
```

is interpreted as

```
find ./ \( \( -path ./publish -prune \) -o \( -iname rdesvc -type f \) \) -print
```

so `./publish` is pruned *and* printed, and anything matching `rdesvc` is printed. (The `-prune` action evaluates to `true`.)