# What is difference between results and effectiveness after adding -f in rm and -print in find?

Tags: shell-script, xargs

I got a task to delete all files which are older than 90 days from `/dir/prd/log` recrusively i.e delete from subdirectries too. I made this command:

```
find /dir/prd/log* -mtime +90 | xargs rm
```

Then I was talking to a unix guy and he suggested

```
find /dir/prd/log* -mtime +90 -print | xargs rm -f
```

I just want to know what would have been his purpose to put "-print" and "-f" in command.

Comment: What OS are you using? Is this Unix or did you mean Linux?

Comment: It's UNIX, will it make a difference?

Comment: Partial duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197824/what-is-the-difference-between-find-and-find-print

Comment: Related: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`-f` tells `rm` to never prompt (*e.g.* when it encounters read-only files) and to ignore missing files it’s asked to delete (instead of indicating an error). It will also not complain if not passed any file to remove.

Here, depending on the `xargs` implementation `rm`'s stdin will be either the pipe from `find` or `/dev/null`, so without `-f`, find may end up reading the answer to those prompts from the output of `find`!

`-print` is the default action for `find` in Linux distributions and [POSIX-compliant systems](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), but might need to be explicitly specified [on very old Unix or Unix-like systems](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/find/#print).

So his purpose was probably to make the command more robust and portable. You could do better with some variants of `find` (going beyond POSIX):

```
find /dir/prd/log -mtime +90 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

avoids problems with filenames containing “special” characters (including space, newline, tab, single quote, double quote, backslash), and if your `find` supports the `-delete` action,

```
find /dir/prd/log -mtime +90 -delete
```

avoids spawning other processes to perform the deletion (and also avoids some race condition issues). (Note that I’m specifying `/dir/prd/log` here to match your stated requirement from the first sentence of your question, as confirmed in the comments.)

With POSIX `find`, you can still avoid `xargs` and filename parsing by asking `find` to run `rm` itself:

```
find /dir/prd/log -mtime +90 -exec rm -f '{}' +
```

Beside being more portable and reliable, it also avoids the issue of `rm` reading prompt answers from `find`'s output mentioned above (it also avoids running `rm` at all if no file is found).

If `/dir/prod/log` contains subdirectories, you’ll want to filter them to avoid error messages since `rm` can’t delete them:

```
find /dir/prd/log ! -type d -mtime +90 -exec rm -f '{}' +
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57460/discussion-on-answer-by-stephen-kitt-what-is-difference-between-results-and-effe).