# Find exclude path containing specific files

Tags: find, directory, path, git

I am trying to find all directories in a folder recursively while exclude all git submodules  by excluding all path containing `.git` file. How could I do it?

---

Explanation:

`.git` file exists at the root of every submodules folder. This submodule folder could be included anywhere.

---

Test Case

```
$ mkdir Test
$ cd Test
$ mkdir a
$ mkdir b
$ mkdir c
$ cd a
$ mkdir .git
$ cd ..
$ cd b
$ touch .git
$ cd ..
$ cd c
$ mkdir c1
$ mkdir c2
$ cd..
$ find . -type d \( \( ! -name . -exec [ -e {}/.git ] \; -prune \) -o \( \( \
 -name .git\
 -o -name .vscode\
 -o -name node_modules\
 -o -name Image\
 -o -name Rendered\
 -o -name iNotebook\
 -o -name GeneratedTest\
 -o -name GeneratedOutput\
  \) -prune \) -o -print \) | sort
```

Expected Results

```
.
./a
./c
./c/c1
./c/c2
```

Comment: No I meant .git files as that is the case for submodules

Comment: excluding .git folder is not a problem as it can be easily done like this `find "$(pwd)" -not \( -path "*/.git"\` \) -type d`

Comment: `.git` file exist at the root of every submodules folder. This submodule folder could be included anywhere

Comment: But I thought you want to exclude folders **containing** .git... So your find doesn't work for that even if its a folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find` actions are also tests, so you can add tests using `-exec`:

```
find . \( -exec [ -f {}/.git ] \; -prune \) -o \( -name .git -prune \) -o -print
```

This applies three sets of actions:

- `-exec [ -f {}/.git ] \; -prune` prunes directories containing a file named `.git`
- `-name .git -prune` prunes directories named `.git` (so the command doesn’t search inside the main `.git` directory of a repository)
- `-print` prints anything which isn’t caught by the above.

To only match directories, add `-type d`, either just before `-print`, or (to save time processing files):

```
find . -type d \( \( -exec [ -f {}/.git ] \; -prune \) -o \( -name .git -prune \) -o -print \)
```

This also works when run this on a directory other than `.`, by changing the `find` start path:

```
find /some/other/path -type d \( \( -exec [ -f {}/.git ] \; -prune \) -o \( -name .git -prune \) -o -print \)
```

Comment: This is really cool. And I thought my solution is clever ;-)

Comment: @Stephen Kitt You mentioned `-name .git -prune` to exclude directories. Is it better to use  `-not -path "*/.git/*"`

Comment: @Nikhil `-not -path "*/.git/*"` checks all the files and directories inside `.git`, which can take a little while, whereas `-name .git -prune` avoids descending into the directory at all; the latter is more efficient.

Comment: @StephenKitt I found one semantic issue.  \( ! -name . -exec [ -e {}/.git ] \; -prune \) is excluding parent folders with .git files as well as .git folder. .git file is present in Submodules. But, .git folder is present in normal repository and we don't want to exclude normal repository.

Comment: @StephenKitt With the Test (See EDIT) your solution does not give desired results. It skips folder `a`

Comment: @Nihil ah yes, I missed the strict “file” requirement. See my updated answer.

Comment: @StephenKitt In [command line - What is the difference between find . and find . -print - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197824/what-is-the-difference-between-find-and-find-print) you mentioned that `find .` and `find . -print` are equivalent. Is it the same for this case as well? Can we skip `-print` here?

Comment: @Nikhil no: `-print` is the default action, used when no other expression is given. Here the `find` command includes other expressions (`-exec`, `-prune`, and `-name`) so we need to specify `-print` explicitly. Try removing `-print`: the `find` command won’t output anything. `find .` and `find . -print` are equivalent as complete commands, not as portions of commands.

Comment: @StephenKitt Using Your example, I tried to find `index.md` while excluding path with `.git` file and `Rendered` directory, like this `find . -type f  \( \( -exec [ -f {}/.git ] \; -prune \) -o \( \(  -name "Rendered"  \) -prune \) -o  -name 'index.md' \) -print | sort`. But it doesn't prunes out `Rendered`? How should I modify this?

Comment: @Nikhil your very first test in that command limits everything else to files, so you’ll never prune any directory. You need to split the tests up to prune directories and then look for `index.md`: `find . \( -type d \( -exec [ -f {}/.git ] \; -o -name "Rendered" \) -prune \) -o \( -type f -name index.md -print \)`.

Comment: @StephenKitt I get same error with: `PruneDir="\( \( -exec [ -f {}/.git ] \; -prune \) -o \( \( -name .git -o -name 'Data' \) -prune \) -o -print \)"; find . -maxdepth 5 -type d ${PruneDir:-};` **Error**: `find: paths must precede expression: \('`

Comment: @Nikhil right, you also need to fix the escaping of your brackets and semi-colons: `PruneDir="( ( -exec [ -f {}/.git ] ; -prune ) -o ( ( -name .git -o -name 'Data' ) -prune ) -o -print )"; find . -maxdepth 5 -type d ${PruneDir:-};`

Comment: @StephenKitt I executed as you said (please see the Gist: [Find With Prune](https://gist.github.com/Agarwal-Nikhil/f6f8c5f30e7afd41b1aadc7869e8c5dc). ) But, the prune is not pruning out the folders.

Answer (score 3):

We can create a recursive `find`:

Add the following lines to a script file:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f "$1"/.git ]; then
    echo "$1"
    find "$1" -mindepth 1 -type d -prune -exec "$0" {} \;
fi
```

I named the file `findifnotgit` but it doesn't matter.
Then make it executable

```
chmod u+x findifnotgit
```

Then run it with the path you want to run as argument:

```
./findifnotgit .
```

--> `.` for current dir

or

```
./findifnotgit /path/to/search/
```

---

**Explanation**:

- `if [ ! -f "$1"/.git ]; then ... fi` Only run the following when there is not `.git` file inside the current folder (`$1`)
- We need `-mindepth 1` option to let find not find the folder we started with which would create an indefinite loop.
- We need `-prune` so that find will not descend into directories. We will do this ourselves inside `-exec`.
- `-exec "$0" {}` will call the same script `$0` with the finds.

Comment: Is it possible to store the results of find in a file like `temp`

Comment: sure, just run `./findifnotgit . > temp`

Comment: Yes, I tried that but all the output lines are prefixed with `[3J[H[2J.` and some special characters.

Comment: this seems to be another issue not related to my answer... https://askubuntu.com/questions/638952/why-are-these-characters-written-to-the-terminal-during-clear/

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a dirty script, but this will find all directories that don't contain a `.git`  file in them:

```
#!/bin/bash

# find dirs that contain *.git files and store in array
exclude_dirs=($(find . -type f -iname ".git" | xargs -i dirname {}))

# set up the base command
command="find . -type d"

# loop over each element in array by index
for i in $(seq 0 $(expr ${#exclude_dirs[@]} - 1)); do
    command="${command} -not -path ${exclude_dirs[$i]}"
done

# run the find
eval ${command}
```

#### edit:

fixed syntax errors and updated `*.git` to `.git`

#### edit2:

yep that was wrong, my apologies. Edited so it actually works now.

Comment: Indeed very dirty ... and did you try it yourself? It doesn't work as you have syntax errors. Also OP wants to exclude `.git` not `*.git`.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry - I was testing two different things and copied the wrong bit.. I've updated it now and double-tested

Comment: Still doesn't work. Please check once more.

Comment: What doesn't work about it for you? are you missing results you expect?

Comment: Works for me now, but does only exclude the path not containing .git file. It does not exclude subdirectories of that path which is I believe what OP intended

Comment: if @Nikhil can clarify that, I'll edit it to do so

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to tell find not to look inside the .git or .hg repositories.

```
find .  \( -iname '.git' -o -iname '.hg' \) -prune -false  -o -iname  '*thing-i-am-looking for*'
```

Comment: do you know something I don't know ? what is `bookmarker`, why `.hg`? Also I thought OP wants to find folders and not anything called `*thing-i-am-looking for*` ?

Comment: Sorry left in file name from test, and I included two things to ignore, so one can see how to extend it.